# Old school sci-fi: Robot escapes planet by riding on the outside of a space ship,

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm sure the book was from a well known old-school sci-fi writer.

A Robot escapes Earth, by magnetically [I think] attaching itself to the outside of a space ship.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SciFi SE. Are you looking for a book series? Or are these two separate books?

Comment: Two separate books, I read them ages ago, was fascinated by them and would like to read them again.

Comment: In that case you will need to [edit the question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/239568/edit) so it is focused on a single book, and then [ask a new question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for the second book. Additionally, please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/39144) and add in as much detail as you can remember to both questions. As it stands they might be closed for lack of details, so anything you remember will help

Comment: I have the answer to question One - it is Clifford Simak's 'short story All the Traps of Earth'. Do I have to wait for Anytus to post the question again before he can read it?

Comment: Lee Dckhardt, Thank you so much its greatly appreciated.   I've been trying to remember that for decades.    I just ordered a copy off of ebay.   Thanks again,

Answer (score 7):

This story is the Clifford D. Simak novelette 'All The Traps Of Earth' from F&SF in 1960. A robot, Richard Daniel, has served the Barrington family for 600 years, but now the family has died out and their estate is to be auctioned off to pay their debts; this includes Richard Daniel. The problem: his 600-year memory will be automatically wiped before he is sold. Determined to keep his memories, Richard Daniel flees to the local spaceport and leaves Earth by clinging to a starship's hull.